# filter to get regular circle light from an LED so it could be analyzed by a camera?

Tags: led

i want to get a uniform light increase and decrease so it could be analyzed by mobile camera is there any kind of filters that could be put over the led so the light would be like regular circle increase and decrease??

Comment: What do you mean with "circle"?

Comment: i mean light not distracted every where i want it in a form of uniform circle

Comment: No punctuation, runon "sentence", not even first letter capatilized.  If you don't care, there is no reason we should.

Comment: @OlinLathrop take it easy it's a simple question!!!

Comment: So instead of fixing your mess you instead complain about people objecting to it!!?  Given the lack of respect, even disdain, you are exhibiting towards those you seek a favor from, you don't deserve any answers here in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the LED light in a circle then you can use a convex lens with the LED at its focus. The light will form a (near) parallel beam with a spot size equal to lens diameter.

This works well enough for small cone angle LEDs' (Cone angle is angle at which light spreads out from LED. ) For cone angles over about 120 degrees this may be less than satisfactory.

Many companies make lenses for LEDs that are aimed at making a parallel beam (for spotlights/ torches).

Example image below is from [here](http://www.candlepowerforums.com/vb/showthread.php?235443-3-XR-E-s-and-a-MC-E) where they are discussing making spots and beams.

[image]

Diagram below and interesting and somewhat related discussions [here](http://www.candlepowerforums.com/vb/showthread.php?214561-Let-s-design-a-road-front-light-beam/page5)

[image]

---

If you want a circle of light and don't mind that some light is lost, then simply shining the LED via a circular aperture or through a round tube will achieve what you want. A tube with the inside painted matt-black works well.

Diffusers / shades of the type shown below do this, but a cardboard tube and matt black spray  paint will do as well.

[image]

Comment: A "snoot" (basically an array of thin tubes within a bigger tube) will work better than a simple tube IMO.

Comment: @0x6d64 - No need to offer your opinion, that mechanism will work better because of physics. :)  Of course, it will cost more, but that's the tradeoff.

Comment: Cost more and probably have more loss.

Comment: @0x6d64 - Snoot would need to be tried in specific appication. Where the source is non-point then having multiple smaller tubes helps pcik out parallel light. For a point source off centre tubes will produce NO light if the point cannot "see" the far end of the snoot and if the tubes are light absorbing inside (eg matt black). ie A snoot works well with many lamps and if a reflector has expanded and somewhat parelleled the light already but may have issues with a point source.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon that's good idea but i want it in very small space , about 4 LEDs infront of a camera and when light increase or decrease from al rheostat the camera capture light increase and decrease (that's why i wanted light be uniform and circular )